# google photos api code 401 Request is missing required authentication credential during mediaItem get

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have some python code that successfully authenticates and pulls back various objects from google photos api.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build


def build_service(credentials):
    API_SERVICE_NAME = 'photoslibrary'
    API_VERSION = 'v1'

    return build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=credentials)

def get_albums(service):
    results = service.albums().list().execute()
    return results.get('albums', [])

def get_pictures(service,album_id: str):
    body = {
        "albumId": album_id,
        "page_size": 10
    }
    print(body)
    results = service.mediaItems().search(body=body).execute()
    return results

def get_picture_url(service,media_item_id: str):
    return service.mediaItems().get(mediaItemId=media_item_id)
```

All functions work except for get_picture_url, which results in the follow response. Working through the shell, I can successfully list mediaItems with the list method, but cannot access them thought the get() method.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

Edit: my scope is set to readonly.

Comment: Could you show exactly which scope you're using? Maybe you can use a very large scope and check if you still get the error.

Comment: sure, my scope is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.readonly`

Comment: I tried using `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary` but this still occurs